# How to implement update step of Quaternion Extended Kalman filter for robot navigation using magnetometer measurement and Lie algebra?

Tags: navigation, linear-algebra, kalman-filter

I am using Extended Kalman Filter for the navigation of autonomous underwater vehicles based on the gyro, accelerometer, magnetometer, DVL (Doppler Velocity Logger), and USBL measurements. I based my code on the Quaternion EKF implementation from https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9444664, where Lie algebra is used for state representation. The state (Xt) is modeled as 5x5 matrix where the first three rows and first three columns form a 3D rotation matrix, the fourth column contains velocity info and the fifth column contains position info.

[image]

The update of the state (mu variable in the code) based on velocity (DVL measurement) is done by the following code:

```
def update_dvl(self, z,  mu, sigma, bias, last_u):
    """Runs correction step of Quaternion-EKF. (Multiplicative EKF)

    Args:
        z (m ndarray): measurement at this step

    Returns:
        mu    (nxn ndarray) : Corrected state
        sigma (nxn ndarray) : Corrected covariances"""
        last_u: (2x3 ndarray) last imu (gyro and acc) measurement
        bias: imu bias
        
    # convert dvl into correct frame
    z = self.dvl_r@z + self.dvl_p@(last_u[0] - bias[0])

    # make H matrix
    zero    = np.zeros((3,3))
    rot = mu[:3,:3] # Rotation Matrix
    v_hat = mu[:3,3] # Velocity  
    H = np.block([self.cross(rot.T@v_hat ), rot.T, zero, zero, zero])

    # make innovation
    V = z - (rot.T@v_hat)  #innovation linear

    # make our special measurement covariance
    meas_cov   = inv(H@sigma@H.T + self.R[:3,:3])
    # Calculate the Kalman Gain
    K = sigma @ H.T @ meas_cov

    K_V = K @ V
    # Update State Estimate
    mu[:3,:3] = mu[:3,:3] @ expm( self.cross( K_V[:3] ) )
    mu[:3,3] += K_V[3:6]
    mu[:3,4] += K_V[6:9]
           
    # Update the Covariance
    sigma = (np.eye(15) - K @ H) @ sigma
    return mu, sigma
```

The Jacobian for the H matrix is computed by finding derivates in Lie space. In this case, this is simple because the measurement function linearly depends on the rotation matrix. However, I would like to include magnetometer measurements as well. Since I am not much familiar with Lie algebra, I am not sure how to do the update step when yaw angle (heading) measurement of the magnetometer is used as input. The yaw angle in my case can be computed from the rotation matrix as:

```
z_hat = np.arctan2(mu[1,0], mu[0,0])
```

However, I don't know how to create an H matrix. Can I use Lie Algebra for this and how?